# Can I do this relational algebra sentence in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-algebra

π LOC, DEPTNO(DEPT) – πDEPTNO (σLOC-‘DALLAS’(DEPT))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schemata of the left and right arguments of operator – (set difference) do not match: {LOC, DEPTNO} ≠ {DEPTNO}.

As is, this relational algebra query could not be evaluated.